# C# executing python script through cmd fails due to insufficient permissions

Tags: c#, cmd, windows-server-2008

I'm attempting to run a command, similar to shell command, to execute a python script which saves a file by starting a Process

```
Process proc = new Process {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/c python c:\\test\\script.py",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    }
};
```

I need to be able to get the standard output back to my c# program, and had to set UseShellExecute to false.

The python script is being executed and I'm getting the output back, but the script isn't getting the permissions to save the file to a folder in the disk. The same file I'm able to save in the c# code.

Is there any way to give the same permissions to the python script as the c# code which executes it.

Strangely, the issue I'm facing is not reproducible on my local machine and only on a windows-server environment.

Comment: I don't know if this would work on Windows Server 2008, but you might want to try adding a `Verb = "runas",` in there.

Comment: Verb=""runas" doesn't work if UAC is turned on.

Comment: Try tunning Visual Studio as administrator

Comment: This is on IIS, already running on a high privilege account.